# How to recycle a bitmap and use it later again?

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I have to free memory occupied by bitmaps. So I'm calling `recycle()` on all of them, when my activities finish.

These bitmaps are always used in drawables, either as background property or source (case of `ImageView`) property.

But the problem is, when later another activity has a view that also uses these bitmaps, it will show

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap.

What can I do, I can't keep the bitmaps in memory only because *maybe* the user starts, at some point later, an activity which uses them. How do I tell the bitmaps to free memory and also please be possible to be used later again?

Comment: Perhaps try and reinitialize the bitmap?

Comment: how? Currently I get them either using `resources.getDrawable(id).getBitmap` or in XML

Comment: Well initially you'll have something like this: 
Bitmap foo;
foo = methodToGetBitmap();
foo.recycle();
foo = methodToGetBitmap();

Comment: Ahm, I'm saying that I get the bitmap, using a method to get the bitmap, then call recycle, and then call the method to get the bitmap again. And then I get an exception, because the second method to get the bitmap tries to reuse it, after it was recycled.

Comment: I already wrote what I'm using, there's nothing more to show, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutionis to initialize the Bitmap and View using this:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.mybitmap);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(b));
```

This does not work for XML bitmaps although. But the bitmap should be retrievable from the view.

Having the bitmap instance in memory, it's possible to call recycle() on it to free memory immediatly.

And *before* recycling the bitmap it has to be ensured that it's not referenced by any view anymore - setting the references of the drawable / view to null. Otherwise the exception will be thrown. In order to do this it's necessary to keep track of the views which are referencing a bitmap and null all the references before recycling it.

So my actual problem was not reusing the bitmap. The problem was recycling the bitmap while is still referenced by a view.

Comment: Ixx, could you please confirm if this solves the issue when the image is defined in XML (i.e. as android:background=) ? I understand that if I initialize it that way I can recycle it safely after?

Answer (score 0):

If all you use the `Bitmap`s for is `Drawable`s and `android:source` of `ImageView`s, then why do you have `Bitmap` objects at all? Android will take care of optimal memory use in those cases and there is no need to call `recycle()` at all.

Comment: Not really (I'm developing for API 7), the bitmaps are kept in memory, more exactly native heap, and if I, for example have an activity with a pager, each slide using a different background, which occupies a lot of memory, and some images over it, then start another activity, which has different backgrounds, it will run out of memory. That's not optimal memory use.

Comment: Hm, well the background activity should in theory be destroyed in this case. Anyway, what exactly are you doing? Something like `((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle()`? Because in that case you should reinitialise the source on reuse.

Comment: Destroy is not always called (tested). I also remember docs saying not to rely on onDestroy() being called. And anyways, the native heap in these older apis seems also not to be cleared when it should. In my case it just keeps growing, and growing... And yes, that's what I'm doing. What do you mean with reinitialize the source? The bitmap? How do I do it?

Comment: Essentially call `setImageBitmap()` or the like again.

Comment: Ok, thanks for now, will use the check from the other answer and find how to initialize, hope that solves it.

Comment: Hope that solves it, but I have to say that if the steps you describe cause a crash, something is done wrong. It's not that there is a bug in older Android versions (I develop for API 4)...

Comment: Which steps do you mean, the ones recycling the bitmaps, or the out of memory crash?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the bitmap is recycled with `bitmap.isRecycled()`. If this method returns true, you can reinitialize the bitmap. Something like this:

```
if(bitmap != null && bitmap.isRecycled()) {
  //Reinitialize the image
}
else {
  //The bitmap is not recycled, you can use it
}
```

Comment: Ok, `isRecycled` is half of the way, will find out how to reinitialize... it seems I will not be able to define them in XML... I come back to this thread later, thanks